# Add element in XML value null

Tags: xml, powershell, element

I'm trying to add a new element in an XML file. Below is the XML file. My goal is to add several new Svc with property Name, Displayname, Activ, CommadState, Status.

As my Svc element doesn't have an ID or other thing, I can not add then edit I've to add directly the correctly value

I've tried like this but it says that I'm trying to call a null-valued expression.

```
$drive = "E:"

$filePath = Get-Content $drive\Alarm\Services\ProgWatch\ProgWatchServices.xml

$doc = New-Object System.Xml.XmlDocument
$doc.Load($filePath)
$child = $doc.CreateElement("Svc")
$doc.DocumentElement.AppendChild($child)
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<ArrayOfSvc xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">   
  <Svc>
    <Name>Respus</Name>
    <Displayname>Respus</Displayname>
    <Activ>true</Activ>
    <CommadState>NoCommand</CommadState>
    <Status>Running</Status>   </Svc>   <Svc>
    <Name>AlarmUS</Name>
    <Displayname>AlarmUS</Displayname>
    <Activ>true</Activ>
    <CommadState>NoCommand</CommadState>
    <Status>Running</Status>   </Svc>   <Svc>
    <Name>asProgWatchGuard</Name>
    <Displayname>Prog Watch Guardian</Displayname>
    <Activ>true</Activ>
    <CommadState>NoCommand</CommadState>
    <Status>Running</Status>   
  </Svc>   
  <Svc>
    <Name>asBackup</Name>
    <Displayname>Data Backup</Displayname>
    <Activ>true</Activ>
    <CommadState>NoCommand</CommadState>
    <Status>Running</Status>   
  </Svc> 
</ArrayOfSvc>
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted the actual error message that you are getting, and also tagged the language/api (it appears that this is C# but are leaving people to guess)

Answer (score 0):

This looks like PowerShell.  Here is code for using Xml Linq net library

```
using assembly System.Xml.Linq

$filename = "c:\temp\test.xml"
$doc = [System.Xml.Linq.XDocument]::Load($filename)
$arrayOfSvc = $doc.Root

$child = [System.Xml.Linq.XElement]::new([System.Xml.Linq.XName]::Get('Svc'))
$arrayOfSvc.Add($child)
$doc
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for this help, but i don't see how can i add the value Name, Displayname, Activ, COmmandState and Status with your code ? thanks

Comment: You need to add a new node like child for  Name, Displayname, Activ, COmmandState and Status.  Then add each node to $child similar to the way child was added to arrayofsvc

Answer (score 0):

**tl;dr**

- For an immediate fix, change `.Load()` to `.LoadXml()`
- A robust and more efficient approach is to pass the file path directly to the `.Load()` method:

```bash
$drive = "E:"

# Note: Be sure to use a *full path*.
$filePath = "$drive\Alarm\Services\ProgWatch\ProgWatchServices.xml"

$doc = New-Object System.Xml.XmlDocument
$doc.Load($filePath)
$child = $doc.CreateElement("Svc") # An empty new element - see also below.
$doc.DocumentElement.AppendChild($child)
```

---

##### Populating a new XML element before insertion:

The above only creates an *empty* `<Svc>` element.
To *populate your new element* it, you have two options:

- Use *methods* to iteratively create the desired structure; e.g.:

  ```bash
  $child = $doc.CreateElement('Svc')
  $grandChild1 = $doc.CreateElement('Name')
  $grandChild1.InnerText = 'newName'
  $grandChild2 = $doc.CreateElement('DisplayName')
  $grandChild2.InnerText = 'newDisplayName'
  # ...
  $null = $child.AppendChild($grandChild1)
  $null = $child.AppendChild($grandChild2)
  # ...
  # Finally, insert the completed new child element into the document
  $null = $doc.DocumentElement.AppendChild($child)
  ```
- More conveniently, use an [`XmlDocumentFragment`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Xml.XmlDocumentFragment) instance, obtained via [`.CreateDocumentFragment()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Xml.XmlDocument.CreateDocumentFragment), to construct the new element from an XML *string* representing the desired structure; e.g.:

  ```bash
  $child = $doc.CreateDocumentFragment()
  $child.InnerXml = '
    <Svc>
      <Name>{0}</Name>
      <Displayname>{1}</Displayname>
      <Activ>{2}</Activ>
      <CommadState>{3}</CommadState>
      <Status>{4}</Status>
    </Svc>
   ' -f 'newName', 'newDisplayName', 'false', 'NoCommand', 'Suspended'
  # Insert the completed new child element into the document
  $null = $doc.DocumentElement.AppendChild($child)
  ```

---

##### Background information re loading XML from files:

Your `$filePath` variable - despite its name - contains *XML text*, because you used [`Get-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Management/Get-Content) with your file path.

Therefore, the *immediate* fix is to use the [`.LoadXml()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Xml.XmlDocument.LoadXml) rather than the [`.Load()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Xml.XmlDocument.Load) method of the [`System.Xml.XmlDocument`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Xml.XmlDocument) class (which you can refer to as `[xml]` in PowerShell).

However, this **two-step approach to loading XML from a file is best avoided**, for the following reasons:

- **Efficiency**: Using the `.Load()` method directly *with a file path* requires only a single call.

  - Note: Be sure to always pass a *full* path to .NET methods, because .NET's working directory usually differs from PowerShell's.
- **Character encoding**:

  - The **`.Load()`** method **defaults to UTF-8** when reading and **notably respects an `encoding` attribute in the XML declaration** (e.g., e.g., `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>`) if the character-encoding is a different one.
  - By contrast, `Get-Content` does *not* do that (it never interprets the content of a file) and in *Windows PowerShell* defaults to ANSI encoding, i.e. the encoding implied by the system's active legacy ANSI code page (by contrast, [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) now commendably default to (BOM-less) UTF-8, across all cmdlets).
  - In other words: **`Get-Content` may misinterpret your XML file.**

    - In combination with the `[xml]` type accelerator, using `Get-Content` is *seductive*, but *not robust*. If you're willing to assume that `Get-Content` *doesn't* misinterpret an XML file or you know the actual encoding and specify it via `-Encoding`, the following *shortcut* is possible; note the use of `-Raw` to read the entire file *as a whole*, which is much faster than the line-by-line reading `Get-Content` performs by default)

      ```bash
       # Convenient, but NOT ROBUST
       # May need an -Encoding argument.
       $doc = [xml] (Get-Content -Raw $filePath)
      ```
    - The **concise formulation of the  *robust* approach** (as shown at the top) is:

      ```bash
       # Still concise, and while more complex, it is ROBUST
       # Note the need for Convert-Path to ensure that a *full path* is passed.
       ($doc = [xml]::new()).Load((Convert-Path $filePath))
      ```