# How to add value in xml using powershell

Tags: xml, powershell

I am novice to programming.

Below is my XML. I am trying with powershell to read the below XML from bigger xml block and add a new member into the xml
I am trying with below powershell but its not working. Could you please help me?

PS C:\Windows\system32> select-xml -Xml $xml.Objects.Object
cmdlet Select-Xml at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
XPath: //role

```
<Members>
            <Member>
              <Name>VSSASWI-0\Mssql</Name>
            </Member>
            <Member>
              <Name>NT SERVICE\SSASTELEMETRY$SERVER</Name>
            </Member>
            <Member>
              <Name>ADDOC\admin</Name>
            </Member>
          </Members>



<Batch xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine' Transaction='true'>
<Alter AllowCreate="true" ObjectExpansion="ObjectProperties" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine">
  <Object />
  <ObjectDefinition>
    <Server xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ddl2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine/2" xmlns:ddl2_2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine/2/2" xmlns:ddl100_100="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2008/engine/100/100" xmlns:ddl200="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2010/engine/200" xmlns:ddl200_200="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2010/engine/200/200" xmlns:ddl300="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2011/engine/300" xmlns:ddl300_300="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2011/engine/300/300" xmlns:ddl400="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2012/engine/400" xmlns:ddl400_400="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2012/engine/400/400" xmlns:ddl500="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2013/engine/500" xmlns:ddl500_500="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2013/engine/500/500">
      <ID>SSASWI-0\SERVER</ID>
      <Name>SSASWI-0\SERVER</Name>
    </Server>
  </ObjectDefinition>
</Alter>
<Alter AllowCreate="true" ObjectExpansion="ObjectProperties" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine">
  <Object>
    <RoleID>Administrators</RoleID>
  </Object>
  <ObjectDefinition>
    <Role xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ddl2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine/2" xmlns:ddl2_2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine/2/2" xmlns:ddl100_100="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2008/engine/100/100" xmlns:ddl200="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2010/engine/200" xmlns:ddl200_200="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2010/engine/200/200" xmlns:ddl300="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2011/engine/300" xmlns:ddl300_300="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2011/engine/300/300" xmlns:ddl400="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2012/engine/400" xmlns:ddl400_400="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2012/engine/400/400" xmlns:ddl500="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2013/engine/500" xmlns:ddl500_500="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2013/engine/500/500">
      <ID>Administrators</ID>
      <Name>Administrators</Name>
      <Members>
        <Member>
          <Name>VSSASWI-0\Mssql</Name>
        </Member>
        <Member>
          <Name>NT SERVICE\SSASTELEMETRY$SERVER</Name>
        </Member>
        <Member>
          <Name>ADDOC\admin</Name>
        </Member>
      </Members>
    </Role>
  </ObjectDefinition>
</Alter>
</Batch>
```

Comment: This is very similar to a posting I answered this morning : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76162846/add-element-in-xml-value-null/76163516#76163516

Answer (score 2):

The code this morning didn't have default namespace so code is a little different

```
using assembly System.Xml.Linq


$filename = 'c:\temp\test.xml'
$doc = [System.Xml.Linq.XDocument]::Load($filename)
$alter = $doc.Root
$ns = $alter.GetDefaultNamespace()

$members = $doc.Descendants($ns + 'Members')[0]
$child = [System.Xml.Linq.XElement]::new([System.Xml.Linq.XName]::Get('Member', $ns))
$members.Add($child)
$doc
```