# In PowerShell, XML children and attributes are object properties. How does it work?

Tags: .net, xml, powershell

In PowerShell, child nodes and attributes of XML elements are accessible as properties:

```
([xml]"<book genre='novel'/>").Book.genre
```

```
novel
```

It is a `Property`, not a `NoteProperty`:

```
([xml]"<book genre='novel'/>").Book | Get-Member genre
```

```
   TypeName: System.Xml.XmlElement

Name  MemberType Definition
----  ---------- ----------
genre Property   string genre {get;set;}
```

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/data/xml/accessing-attributes-in-the-dom) says:

> Attributes are properties of the element, ...

Although, in C#, there are no such properties:

```cs
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml("<book genre='novel'/>");
// Console.WriteLine(doc.Book);  // Does not work
// Console.WriteLine(doc.DocumentElement.genre);  // Does not work
```

```
'XmlDocument' does not contain a definition for ...
```

Is it a PowerShell feature? Or is it a .NET feature I am using incorrectly?

What is the mechanism used to implement these properties?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**tl;dr**

- You're seeing ***PowerShell's adaptation* of the XML DOM** (.NET type [`System.Xml.XmlDocument`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Xml.XmlDocument), available via [type accelerator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Type_Accelerators) `[xml]` in PowerShell), which **presents XML child elements and attributes *as properties***, allowing for **convenient access** to them **via *dot notation***.

  - *Adaptation* of .NET types is one among several features offered by PowerShell's **[ETS (Extended Type System)](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/PowerShell-Docs/issues/6763)**.
- To see only the .NET *type-native* members of a given type's instance, pass `-View Base` to [`Get-Member`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-member); e.g.:

  ```bash
  # -View Base excludes the *adapted* and possibly other ETS properties.
  [xml] '<foo/>' | Get-Member -View Base
  ```

---

##### Background information:

**PowerShell *decorates* the object hierarchy** contained in [`System.Xml.XmlDocument`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Xml.XmlDocument) instances (created with cast `[xml]`, for instance):

- **with properties *named for the input document's specific elements and attributes***<sup>[1]</sup> at every level; e.g.:

  ```bash
   ([xml] '<foo><bar>baz</bar></foo>').foo.bar # -> 'baz'
   ([xml] '<foo><bar id="1" /></foo>').foo.bar.id # -> '1'
  ```
- **turning *multiple elements of the same name* at a given hierarchy level implicitly into *arrays*** (specifically, of type `[object[]]`); e.g.:

  ```bash
   ([xml] '<foo><C>one</C><C>two</C></foo>').foo.C[1] # -> 'two'
  ```

As the examples (and your own code in the question) show, this allows for **access via convenient *dot notation***.

Note:

- If you use dot notation to **target an element that has at least one *attribute* and/or *child* elements**, the **element *itself* is returned** (an  [`XmlElement`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Xml.XmlElement) instance); **otherwise, it is the element's *text content***; e.g.:

  ```bash
  # The <bar> element's *text content* is returned, as a [string] ('baz'),
  # because it has only a text child node and no attributes
  ([xml] '<foo><bar>baz</bar></foo>').foo.bar

  # The <bar> element is returned as an XmlElement instance,
  # because it has an *attribute*.
  ([xml] '<foo><bar id="1">baz</bar></foo>').foo.bar

  # The <bar> element is returned as an XmlElement instance,
  # because it has *child elements*.
  ([xml] '<foo><bar><baz>quux</baz></bar></foo>').foo.bar
  ```
- ***Updating* XML documents via dot notation** is **limited to *simple, non-structural* changes**; the difference above comes into play:

  ```bash
  # OK - direct updating of the text content of a simple
  # element (no child nodes, no attributes).
  # $xml.foo.bar then yields 'new'
  ($xml = [xml] '<foo><bar>baz</bar></foo>').foo.bar = 'new'

  # OK - direct updating of the attribute of an
  # element.
  #  $xml.foo.bar.id then yields '2'
  ($xml = [xml] '<foo><bar id="1">baz</bar></foo>').foo.bar.id = 2

  # !! FAILS - because <bar> isn't a simple element in this case,
  # !! due to the presence of an *attribute*, you cannot directly assign new text content.
  # !! -> Error "Cannot set "bar" because only strings can be used as values to set XmlNode properties."
  ($xml = [xml] '<foo><bar id="1">baz</bar></foo>').foo.bar = 'new'

  # OK - assign to the type-native .InnerText property
  #  $xml.foo.bar.InnerText then yields 'new'
  ($xml = [xml] '<foo><bar id="1">baz</bar></foo>').foo.bar.InnerText = 'new'
  ```

  - For ***structural* changes**, use of the native methods of [`System.Xml.XmlDocument`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Xml.XmlDocument) is required, which is significantly more complex. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76174333/45375) for an example.

The **downside** of dot notation is that there can be **name collisions**, if an *incidental* input-XML element name happens to be the same as either an *intrinsic* `[System.Xml.XmlElement]` property name (for *single-element* properties), or an intrinsic `[Array]` property name (for *array*-valued properties; `[System.Object[]]` derives from `[Array]`).

**In the event of a *name collision*:** If the property being accessed contains:

- a ***single* child element** (`[System.Xml.XmlElement]`), the ***incidental* properties win**; e.g.:

  ```bash
  # -> 'foo': i.e .the <foo> element's own name, using 
  # XmlElement's type-native .Name property.
  ([xml] '<foo><Bar>bar</Bar></foo>').foo.Name

  # -> !! 'bar': That is, the *adapted* .Name property - i.e. the 
  #    !! child element whose name happened to be "Name" takes precedences.
  ([xml] '<foo><Name>bar</Name></foo>').foo.Name
  ```

  - The **workaround** to get predictable access to the *type-native* properties is to call the underlying property accessor method, **`.get_<propertyName>()`**, directly:

    ```bash
    # -> 'foo', thanks to .get_Name() workaround
    ([xml] '<foo><Name>bar</Name></foo>').foo.get_Name()
    ```

    - An **alternative** is to use the [intrinsic **`psbase`** property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Intrinsic_Members#object-views):

      ```bash
      # -> 'foo', thanks to .psbase workaround
      ([xml] '<foo><Name>bar</Name></foo>').foo.psbase.Name
      ```
- **an *array* of child elements**, **the *`[Array]` type's* properties win.**

  - Therefore, **the following element names break dot notation with *array-valued* properties** (obtained with reflection command
    `Get-Member -InputObject 1, 2 -Type Properties, ParameterizedProperty`):

    ```bash
    Item Count IsFixedSize IsReadOnly IsSynchronized Length LongLenth Rank SyncRoot
    ```

    - For example, trying to use [member-access enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Member-Access_Enumeration) to get all `item` attribute values across all `<bar>` elements:

      ```bash
      # !! Outputs the definition of the parameterized .Item property
      # !! of type [Array], 
      # !! *not* the values of the "Item" attributes of the <bar> child elements.
      ([xml] '<foo><bar item="one" /><bar item="two" /></foo>').foo.bar.item
      ```
    - The **workaround** is to use ***explicit* enumeration of array-valued properties**, e.g. via the [intrinsic `.ForEach()` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Arrays#foreach):

      ```bash
      # -> 'one', 'two'
      ([xml] '<foo><bar item="one" /><bar item="two" /></foo>').foo.bar.ForEach('item')
      ```

**Dot nation is invariably case-*insensitive* - unlike XML itself**, which is an inevitable consequence of representing elements and attribute as *properties*, given that property access in PowerShell is generally case-insensitive:

```bash
 # Dot notation: case-INSENSITIVE
 # -> 'bar', despite the case mismatch
 ([xml] '<FOO>bar</FOO>').foo
 # -> 'BAR', 'bar', i.e. *both* elements that match case-insensitively
 ([xml] '<root><FOO>BAR</FOO><foo>bar</foo></root>').root.foo

 # Type-native XML method: case-SENSITIVE
 # -> NO output, due to the case mismatch
 ([xml] '<FOO>bar</FOO>').SelectSingleNode('foo')
```

**Dot notation *ignores XML namespaces*** - unlike XML-native functionality:

```bash
 # Dot notation: Namespaces are ignored.
 # -> the <foo> element (as a whole, because it has attributes)
 #    despite not specifying the namespace.
 ([xml] '<ns1:foo xmlns:ns1="https://example.org">bar</ns1:foo>').foo

 # Type-native XML methods: Explicit namespace handling required:
 # -> No output
 ([xml] '<ns1:foo xmlns:ns1="https://example.org">bar</ns1:foo>')['foo']

 # -> OK - explicit use of the namespace prefix;
 ([xml] '<ns1:foo xmlns:ns1="https://example.org">bar</ns1:foo>')['ns1:foo']

 # -> No output; see below.
 ([xml] '<ns1:foo xmlns:ns1="https://example.org">bar</ns1:foo>').SelectSingleNode('foo')
```

- For [XPath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath) queries with the type-native [`.SelectSingleNode()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Xml.XmlDocument.SelectSingleNode) / [`.SelectNodes()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Xml.XmlDocument.SelectNodes) methods, you need not only the use of namespace *prefixes*, but you first need to create a namespace *manager* that maps the prefixes used in queries to their namespace URIs - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73027077/45375) for an example of this technique.
  The same applies analogously to the [`Select-Xml`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-xml) cmdlet, which uses XPath queries too - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74181458/45375) for an example.

---

<sup>[1] If a given element has both an attribute *and* and element by the same name, PowerShell reports *both*, as the elements of an *array* `[object[]]`.</sup>

Comment: Superb and excellent comprehensive technical detail!

Comment: ETS. This is what it's called :) It definitely lacks an `about_` topic. Thank you for this and the linked answers. Great examples of XML manipulation in PowerShell.